# SAS Compare every variable with every other variable in a specific calculation

Tags: loops, macros, sas

I'm facing the problem that I have a sample of 262 stocks. Now I have to do a calculation for every possible combination of a pairing of these stocks.
I was thinking about taking two loops. But the way I coded it, I do not even get any output or a notification of an error in the log window.
First I put all my ticker symbols in a macro varibale by using proc sql.

```
proc sql noprint;
select distinct name
into :ticker separated by " "
from stocks;
quit;



%macro close2;
%let n=262; /*262 stocks*/

%do i=1 %to &n.-1;
%do j=i-1 %to &n.;

%let s1=%trim(%scan(&ticker.,&i.," "));
%let s2=%trim(%scan(&ticker.,&j.," "));


data close;
set normp;
closeness=(&s1.-&s2.)**2;
run;

proc means data=close noprint; 
var closeness;
output out=close1 (drop=_type_ _freq_)
sum(closeness)=closen;
run;quit;

data=close1;
set close1;
&s1.%s2.=closen;
run;

%end;
%end;
%mend close2;
```

In the end I want to have all the different sums of the var "closeness" named with the two tickersymbols of the two stocks I calculated it with.

Comment: Do you have PROC IML?

Comment: You have 262 variables in one dataset, and how many rows?

Comment: for this calculation i need 250 rows

Comment: yes i think i have proc iml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be Loopy (http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/183-2007.pdf)

I assume you have a date column or other identifier for the comparison.

Some fake data:

```
%let nStocks=200;

data stocks;
array S[&nStocks];
do date=1 to 10;
    do st=1 to &nStocks;
        S[st] = rannor(1);
    end;
    output;
end;
drop st;
run;
```

Transpose this so that it is "long and skinny" instead of "short and wide"

```
proc transpose data=stocks out=stocks_t(rename=(_name_=Stock1 col1=S1_value));
by date;
run;
```

A sort to make sure everything is the same order (will be important in a minute) and a PROC SQL step to get the names of the stocks.

```
proc sort data=stocks_t;
by date Stock1;
run;

proc sql noprint;
select distinct Stock1
    into :stocks separated by ' '
    from stocks_t
    order by Stock1;
quit;

%put &stocks;
```

Now use a Data Step to look through the data.  Use a hash table and a loop to add the different combinations for each date.  Calculate the "closeness".

```
data need;
set stocks_t;
if _n_=1 then do;
    %create_hash(lk,date Stock2, S2_Value,"stocks_t(rename=(Stock1=Stock2 S1_Value=S2_value))");
end;
by date;

stocks = "&stocks";

if first.date then
    count = 1;

count + 1;

do j=count to &nStocks;
    Stock2 = scan(stocks,j);
    S2_value = .;
    rc = lk.find();
    closeness=(S1_Value-S2_Value)**2;
    C_Var = catt(Stock1,Stock2);
    output;
end;

drop rc count stocks j;
run;
```

From here, you just need to do your sum and you are done:

```
proc summary data=need;
var closeness;
class C_Var;
output out=closeness(where=(C_Var^="") drop=_type_ _freq_) sum=;
run;
```

`%create_hash()` macro from here: https://github.com/FinancialRiskGroup/SASPerformanceAnalytics